# SharePoint 2013 - Outlook synchronization

Tags: 2013, outlook, site-mailboxes

If I want to add the site mailbox feature on the site collection i get this:

> The feature being activated is a Site scoped feature which has a
>   dependency on a Farm scoped feature which has not been activated.
>   Please activate the following feature before trying again: Site
>   Mailboxes 3a11d8ef-641e-4c79-b4d9-be3b17f9607c

And if I connect to outlook in the documents library, it only synchronizes my account.
I want all outlook accounts to be synchronized.

Situation:
I see SharePoint documents under SharePoint lists in outlook. but not everyone can see the list.

Comment: Can someone help me, I find it difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate the `CollaborationMailboxFarm` Farm level feature. Here is PowerShell:

```
$feature = Get-SPFeature CollaborationMailboxFarm -Farm -ErrorAction Ignore

if($feature -eq $NULL)
{
    Write-Host "Enabling Site Mailboxes for Farm"
    Enable-SPFeature CollaborationMailboxFarm
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Site Mailboxes already enabled for Farm"
}
```

And then configure the site where you want to use site mailboxes feature:

```
Enable-SPFeature "CollaborationMailbox" -Url $url
```

See more [Configure site mailboxes in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj552524.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

yes I did and now I get this:

Your SharePoint Server configuration is not supported
Your organization's SharePoint Server configuration is not supported. Please contact your system administrator for more information.

Correlation ID: 38f6f49b-23d7-903f-1e78-04e99cad6245, Error Code 101

Tue Jan 15 2013 08:57:41 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Site Mailboxes are only supported with Sharepoint 2013 connected to Exchange 2013.