# Site Mailbox feature doesn't work in SharePoint 2013

Tags: outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SharePoint 2013 - Outlook synchronization](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55190/sharepoint-2013-outlook-synchronization)

Site Mailbox, this is what i get:

> The feature being activated is a Site scoped feature which has a
>   dependency on a Farm scoped feature which has not been activated.
>   Please activate the following feature before trying again: Site
>   Mailboxes 3a11d8ef-641e-4c79-b4d9-be3b17f9607c

Comment: Please don't post the same or very similar question twice - this will just annoy everybody and reduce your chance of getting an answer.